# Regular Expression in PHP to Match HTML '<p>' that are AFTER the first '<H1>' tag

Tags: php, html, regex

How do I write the Regular Expression in PHP to match HTML `<p>` that are AFTER the first `<H1>` tag?

For example the following states if not equal to the expression

```
if(!preg_match_all('#<p(.*?)<\/p>#', $page_content, $matches)
```

Comment: You should *never* parse HTML with regex. Use [a PHP DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) instead.

Comment: If you really had to do this in regex you'll need the `h1` in your regex, and you'll want the `s` modifier so the `.` extends to new lines.

Comment: Where would I add the H1 and s modifier?

Comment: Use an HTML parser, eg: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ https://github.com/paquettg/php-html-parser

Answer (score 0):

In properly written HTML (i.e HTML that isn't designed to break all sorts of parsers by [abusing the loopholes in SGML specification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/702222)), all `<h1>`s will have corresponding closing tags. That means you can simply look for a `<p>` preceded by a `</h1>`.

```
<\/h1>[\s\S]*?<p>([\s\S]*?)<\/p>
```

Here's how the above regex works, and [a proof of concept](https://regex101.com/r/JahaOR/2):

- `<\/h1>` matches `</h1>` literally
- `[\s\S]*?` matches all characters until the next `<p>`
- `<p>` matches `<p>` literally
- `([\s\S]*?)` matches all characters until the next `</p>` (note the capturing group - **this group contains what you want**)
- `<\/p>` matches `</p>` literally